# Missing Storage

Tags: linux, partitioning, storage

I am using a Raid1 1.2TB storage on my HP server but when I type `df --total -BG` I get a total of 32GB only! :

```
Filesystem           1G-blocks  Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/rootvg-root
                           10G    1G        9G  10% /
tmpfs                       4G    1G        4G   1% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1                   1G    1G        1G  30% /boot
/dev/mapper/rootvg-home
                            1G    1G        1G   1% /home
/dev/mapper/rootvg-opt
                            4G    2G        2G  55% /opt
/dev/mapper/rootvg-osmf
                            4G    1G        4G   2% /osmf/mgmt
/dev/mapper/rootvg-scheduler
                            1G    1G        1G   2% /osmf/mgmt/scheduler
/dev/mapper/rootvg-usr
                            5G    2G        4G  34% /usr
/dev/mapper/rootvg-var
                            4G    1G        4G  12% /var
none                        1G    1G        1G   1% /tmp
total                       32G    5G       26G  17%
```

but then I type fdisk -l and I find

```
 Disk /dev/sda: 1200.2 GB 
    ...
    Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
    /dev/sda1   *           1          64      512000   83  Linux
    Partition 1 does not end on cylinder boundary.
    /dev/sda2              64      145918  1171566592   8e  Linux LVM
    ...
```

I assumed /dev/sda2 is not mounted and this is where the rest of the storage is so I tried to mount it and I get this message:

```
# mount /dev/sda2 /mnt -t ext4
mount: /dev/sda2 already mounted or /mnt busy
```

Any idea where I could find my missing storage?

Thanks

Comment: What do the `pvs`, `vgs`, `lvs`, `lsblk -o name,kname,size,type,fstype,mountpoint` commands output? Even though /dev/sda1 isn't mounted _directly_, it's still in use – there's a LVM layer in between.

Answer (score 0):

thank for helping grawity I just found out how to fix it.

I just needed to extend the logical partitions with lvextend -L'number'G 'partition name'

```
lvextend -L50G /dev/mapper/rootvg-opt
```

Fixed my issue.
Thanks